# List files in directory in codeigniter/php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to list all files within a directory alphabetically.  For the most part, what I have works but there are some strange random ones at the bottom of the list which get mixed up.

Can anyone help?

```
$files = directory_map('downloads/human_resources');

asort($files);

foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_string($file)){
        echo $file[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you have? What do you expect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use directory helper of codeigniter. To load helper use `$this->load->helper('directory');`

and use directory_map() function to read the directory path specified in the first parameter and builds an array representation of it and all its contained files. Example:

```
$map = directory_map('./mydirectory/');
```

Note: Paths are almost always relative to your main index.php file.

Sub-folders contained within the directory will be mapped as well. If you wish to control the recursion depth, you can do so using the second parameter (integer). A depth of 1 will only map the top level directory:

```
$map = directory_map('./mydirectory/', 1);
```

By default, hidden files will not be included in the returned array. To override this behavior, you may set a third parameter to true (boolean):

```
$map = directory_map('./mydirectory/', FALSE, TRUE);
```

Each folder name will be an array index, while its contained files will be numerically indexed. Here is an example of a typical array:

```
Array
(
   [libraries] => Array
   (
       [0] => benchmark.html
       [1] => config.html
       [database] => Array
       (
             [0] => active_record.html
             [1] => binds.html
             [2] => configuration.html
             [3] => connecting.html
             [4] => examples.html
             [5] => fields.html
             [6] => index.html
             [7] => queries.html
        )
       [2] => email.html
       [3] => file_uploading.html
       [4] => image_lib.html
       [5] => input.html
       [6] => language.html
       [7] => loader.html
       [8] => pagination.html
       [9] => uri.html
)
```